# Printing with HP laserJet 10xx in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I am having a problem with with printing from .Net 2.0 on HP LaserJet 10xx printers.

Occasionally (sometimes once a month, sometimes once a day) printer gets 'blocked' in such a manner that it can not print anything from .net 2.0.

When printDocument.print method is invoked, it throws InvalidPrinterException, even if printer has just been selected from printDialog. Printer is online and working (everything else can be printed on it), only printing that goes through .net is blocked.

I have discovered that problem is in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\DevModePerUser
```

If this key exists, PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid reports 'false'. The moment this key is erased PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid is 'true' and printer is working. Right now I am solving this the following way: If printer is "HP" and PrinterSettings is 'false' then check if registry key exists, erase the key and then do the printing. Now, I am aware this is lame, but so far I haven't been able to discover why this happens. I emphasize that this only happens with HP LaserJet 10xx printers. Printing from .NET is completely blocked until this registry key exists.

Has anyone seen such error and if yes, what is the solution?

---

Edit: here is the registry key that bloks the HP1005 printer.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\DevModePerUser]
"HP LaserJet P1005"=hex:48,00,50,00,20,00,4c,00,61,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,4a,00,\
  65,00,74,00,20,00,50,00,31,00,30,00,30,00,35,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,04,02,01,\
  dc,00,44,05,01,00,00,00,01,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,64,00,01,00,07,00,58,02,01,\
  00,01,00,58,02,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,02,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,02,01,00,00,48,00,50,00,20,00,4c,00,61,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,4a,00,65,\
  00,74,00,20,00,50,00,31,00,30,00,30,00,35,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,20,06,00,00,ac,0b,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,20,06,00,00,6c,06,00,00,00,00,00,00,12,00,00,00,ec,13,00,00,\
  c8,19,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,64,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,00,0f,27,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,96,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,34,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,17,00,\
  00,e2,20,00,00,ff,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,12,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  40,17,00,00,e2,20,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,64,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,64,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,ff,ff,ff,ff,40,17,00,00,e2,20,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
```

Comment: What kind of .NET program? Windows Forms? What happens if you exit the program and start again?

Comment: Windows forms program. Exiting the program doesn't change anything. All .NET printing is blocked until that key exists. Even the smallest .NET print sample program fails to print. Printing from non-.NET programs is working well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes it, but it might be helpful to you to know what application is setting that key. Try using the Registry monitoring tools in Process Monitor, from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: I have already tried it. The problem is that key appears randomly and occasionally. Sometimes weeks pass by without a glitch. Sometimes it appears few times a day.